# Joomla multiple functions in single model/view

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to create a drop down list that populates a `<select>` with options pulled from a `DISTINCT` argument.  Code looks like this:

```
function cityData() {
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT MSTCITY FROM " . $db->nameQuote('#__mls') . " ORDER BY MSTCITY;";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $tbl = $db->loadObjectList();
    echo $tbl;
}
```

Now, I have two views: one is RAW for an AJAX call and the other is the default view.  I figured the simplest way would be to just use the default view and do it in PHP, since the default view wasn't really being used for much anyway.  So I added a function:

```
function dropList($tpl = null){
    $model = &$this->getModel();
    $array = $model->cityData();
    $this->assignRef('array', $array );
    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

And then a call in the page

```
<?php 
    $thing = $this->array;
    echo $thing;
?>
```

Nothing is being displayed for the `echo $thing;`.  In the past, when I used PHP to build content instead of AJAX, this worked fine.  I don't know if it's using `loadObjectList()` that's not giving me anything or what.  I know the mySQL query works, as it's be tested in the cmd and I get the result I expect.

Comment: You can't echo an array.

Also why are you using & and unless you are in 1.5 (and even then!) use the modern way of setting a dbo.
http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/9-developer/135-database-upgrades-in-joomla-16.html

Comment: I don't think you return with `echo`.  Also, where does your page call `dropList()` to fill in the value of `$this->array`?

Comment: First ever Joomla site.  Still haven't really gotten the hang of it.

Comment: Doesn't `assignRef()` give that function a a reference to call on the page, which is then called with `$thing = $this->array'`?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?  Where is this code located in your MVC? 

What you need to do is stop fighting with the API and start letting it do the work for you.   There are tons of examples in the core of almost anything you could want to do.  If you want a drop down in the middle of a page take a look at com_contact single contact which has the option of displaying a drop down list o all other contacts. That seems similar to what you want.  Just copy and modify that code.
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default.php#L46

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug and see the array values you need to use print_r.
In your case edit the default.php file to

```
<?php 
$thing = $this->array;
print_r($thing);
?>
```

You can also use var_dump